# What is the explanation for being able to simplify 'A^(B^C) mod prim' such that it is efficiently computable?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, exponentiation, modulo, theorem

## Prelude

We want compute the [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) A<sup>(B<sup>C)</sup></sup> mod p = ?, where `A`, `B`, `C`, and `p` are known and `p` is a prim number. For example: 2<sup>4<sup>3</sup></sup>mod 23 = 6

If we compute it in a straightforward way, first B<sup>C</sup> = e, and then A<sup>e</sup> = n, and finally n mod p; we will run into the problem of creating (potentially) very large intermediary results for e and n. For example: e = 4<sup>3</sup> = 64, n = 2<sup>64</sup> ≈ 1.845x10<sup>19</sup>, and finally n mod 23 = 6

However, doing it in the straightforward way we did not take advantage of the fact that p is a prim number and that we are doing modular exponentiation. And also doing so, we will run into problems computing the result with a computer program in terms of *time* (CPU) and *space* (memory).

(Yes, we could do *fast modular exponentiation* using the identity `(a ⋅ b) mod m = [(a mod m) ⋅ (b mod m)] mod m` by first reducing A<sup>(B<sup>C)</sup></sup> mod p to A<sup>e</sup> mode p. For exmaple A<sup>2</sup> mod p = (A ⋅ A) mod p = [(A mod p) ⋅ (A mod p)] mod p – but that is not where we want to go with this).

## The smart way – use *Fermat's little theorem*

As documented in [Find power of power under mod of a prime](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-power-power-mod-prime/) on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org) and *the origin of this question*, our exponent B<sup>C</sup> in A<sup>(B<sup>C)</sup></sup> mod p can be expressed differently using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Fermat's little theorem states: a<sup>(p - 1)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p) if p is a prime

Leading to following transformations:

1. *It is possible to rewrite* the exponent B<sup>C</sup> as x ⋅ (p - 1) + y
2. Using that alternate expression our A<sup>B<sup>C</sup></sup> becomes A<sup>x ⋅ (p - 1) + y</sup> = A<sup>x ⋅ (p - 1)</sup> ⋅ A<sup>y</sup>
3. Using *Fermat's little theorem* A<sup>x ⋅ (p - 1)</sup> = 1; computing A<sup>(B<sup>C)</sup></sup> mod p becomes computing A<sup>y</sup>
4. Using B<sup>C</sup> = x ⋅ (p - 1) + y then y can be written as B<sup>C</sup> mod (p - 1)

From the above we get A<sup>(B<sup>C)</sup></sup> mod p = (A<sup>y</sup>) mod p

And with all of that we can compute A<sup>(B<sup>C)</sup></sup> mod p in two steps while keeping the intermediary results small.

1. y = (B<sup>C</sup>) mod (p - 1)
2. result = (A<sup>y</sup>) mod p

For example: 2<sup>4<sup>3</sup></sup>mod 23

1. y = 4<sup>3</sup> mod (23 - 1) = 64 mod 22 = 20
2. result = 2<sup>20</sup> mod 23 = 1048576 mod 23 = 6

## Question

My question is about above transformations, and I could not find an (easy to understand) explanation anywhere. Also intensly looking at [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) did not help. Possibly these transformations should be obvious, but it is simply not clear to me.

In particular, I do not understand why the exponent B<sup>C</sup> can be expressed as x ⋅ (p - 1) + y. – What is the reasoning behind this?

And also, why should it be "obvious" when using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem):

a<sup>(p - 1)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p) that A<sup>x ⋅ (p - 1)</sup> = 1?

It would be great if someone could explain those transformations in an easy understandable way.

Comment: This seems like a maths problem more than a programming one per se.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I agree – it's a math understanding problem. To me it isn't obvious whether this question is or isn't [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Still, this question is about understanding a software algorithm which is relevant when trying to do this kind of computation and solving (very likely) number overflows.

Comment: Should this question not get any answers here – you may also want to consider asking your question either on the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or (may be) the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange sites. In any case, be sure to check their respective help pages (what's on-topic, how to ask) before posting there.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to it) when it answers your question. In this way your question isn't showing up as unanswered in the searches anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Let me address the two main questions you have:

> In particular, I do not understand why the exponent B<sup>C</sup> can be expressed as x ⋅ (p - 1) + y. – What is the reasoning behind this?

*Any* integer k can be expressed as k = xm + y for some modulus m. Think of it as dividing k by m, and getting the *quotient* x and the *remainder* y. So let k = B<sup>C</sup> and m = p - 1 and tada.

If it helps you understand, an analogy is that you can turn any amount of minutes into "hours + minutes", when m = 60, then x = hours, y = remaining minutes.

> And also, why should it be "obvious" when using Fermat's little theorem:
>
> a<sup>(p - 1)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p) that A<sup>x ⋅ (p - 1)</sup> = 1?

Say we have a<sup>(p - 1)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p). What happens if we multiply both sides by a<sup>(p - 1)</sup>? We get:

a<sup>(p - 1)</sup> a<sup>(p - 1)</sup> ≡ a<sup>(p - 1)</sup> (mod p)
    a<sup>(p - 1) + (p - 1)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p)                (z<sup>x</sup>z<sup>y</sup> = z<sup>x+y</sup> and the right hand side is equivalent to 1 as we've seen before)
    a<sup>2(p - 1)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p)

We can repeatedly multiply both sides by  a<sup>(p - 1)</sup> to get a<sup>3(p - 1)</sup>, a<sup>4(p - 1)</sup>, etc, so we say that for any integer x we have a<sup>x(p - 1)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p).

Comment: I think that's an understandable explanation for steps (1) and (3). Although it wasn't asked for specifically in the question; maybe you want to extend your answer for the last step, (4): Using B^C = x ⋅ (p - 1) + y then y can be written as B^C mod (p - 1)?

Comment: @IvoMori I think I also explain that by explaining that *y* is the *remainder*.

Comment: Agree (just needed to think about it for a second myself – didn't had my coffee yet), if  any integer n can be expressed as x ⋅ (p - 1) + y  as you explained for (1) – then the remainder y of that n is n mod (p-1). If n is B^C then y = B^C mod (p-1).